# extract values between special characters using R

Tags: regex, r

I would like to extract the values between `[` and `,` and put these extracted values in a new column (`col2`).

I am not opposed to using `stringr` instead of base.

Example data:

```
df <- structure(list(t = structure(1:2, .Label = c("v1", "v2"), class = "factor"), 
    d = structure(1:2, .Label = c("something[123,894]", "something[456,4834]"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("t", "d"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Looks like:

```
   t                   d
1 v1  something[123,894]
2 v2 something[456,4834]
```

Now I would like to make a new column (`df$r`) and extract the values `123` for `v1` and `456` for `v2` into `df$r`.

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this using regex searching for `[` and `,` but I'm not any good using `regex`.

Thanks for your help.

-cherrytree

Comment: ah, you just want the first string? I was doing both. I think one is easier `df$r <- gsub('.*\\[(\\d{3}).*', '\\1', df$d)`

Comment: @rawr, that's a nice solution, though I wonder if OP always has always 3 digits in the first number within the brackets.

Comment: Great question @DavidArenburg, it does NOT always have 3 digits...it can vary from 1 to 4 digits.

Comment: @cherrytree then replace the `{3}` with a `+` :)

Comment: @rawr, I guess you should post it this

Comment: Yep, post it as an answer and I will choose it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df <- structure(list(t = structure(1:2, .Label = c("v1", "v2"), class = "factor"), 
                     d = structure(1:2, .Label = c("something[123,894]", "something[456,4834]"
                     ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("t", "d"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

this will match any character any number of times `.*` and a `[`, then capture to group `\\1` one or more digits `\\d+`, end capture group, followed by any character any number of times

```
df$r <- gsub('.*\\[(\\d+).*', '\\1', df$d)

#    t                   d   r
# 1 v1  something[123,894] 123
# 2 v2 something[456,4834] 456
```

Also, if you want to capture the second string of digits after the comma, this would be more useful:

```
gsub('.*\\[(\\d+),(\\d+).*', '\\1', df$d)
# [1] "123" "456"
gsub('.*\\[(\\d+),(\\d+).*', '\\2', df$d)
# [1] "894"  "4834"
```

Or if you want to do both in one go:

```
cbind(df, do.call('rbind', lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$d), ','),
                                  function(x) gsub('\\D', '', x))))

#    t                   d   1    2
# 1 v1  something[123,894] 123  894
# 2 v2 something[456,4834] 456 4834
```

[This](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=.*%5C%5B%28%5Cd%2B%29%2C%28%5Cd%2B%29.*) explains better than I do:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```